# Fetching data that matches a value.

Tags: python, fetch

For population

```
popfrance = 10000
popchina = 202434
popcanberra = 102042
popengland = 224309
popgermany = 203454
popgoldcoast = 90323
popmelbourne = 100000
popparis = 224224
popperth = 10000
popsydney = 292403
```

Then :

```
dic = {'canberra': 79693.11338661514,
       'china': 40246.748450913066,
       'england': 3043.004178666758,
       'france': 0.0,
       'germany': 21558.2996208357,
       'gold coast': 67781.1426515405,
       'melbourne': 92804.01912347642,
       'paris': 40908.82213277263,
       'perth': 65046.35819797423,
       'sydney': 43786.0579097594}
distance = 10000
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    # k points to the key, and v points to the value
    if v < distance:
        print k,"is within distance", distance
    else:    
        print k,"is outside distance",distance
```

Which produces the names of places and if they are within a distance. I have earlier in the code stored data for each population i.e France = 100000 people (not realistic but testing)

What I want to know please. Is there a way that I can get all the data for the places that appear in the greater than list. i.e if distance = 10 and france is outside distance. Can I then call the population data for France at all? Basically I want it so that if a place is outside distance load its population data. Is this achievable in python?

Comment: What is `dic`? Your question is very unclear to me. Please expand your example and explain more clearly what you want to happen, and what is currently happening.

Comment: @Lattyware Well dic is a list of places and distances and I wanted to compare the distance to a distance and see if it is inside or outside. If it is outside load data for population. Is that clearer?

Comment: So why does your current code not work? Replace the printing with loading the data, and it fits your spec.

Comment: @Lattyware Well my current code prints out just the place and if it is outside the distance. I dont know how I would call/load data for each place outside distance which is my question

Answer (score 1):

You likely want this:

```
distance_dict = {
   'canberra': 79693.11338661514,
   'china': 40246.748450913066,
   'england': 3043.004178666758,
   'france': 0.0,
   'germany': 21558.2996208357,
   'gold coast': 67781.1426515405,
   'melbourne': 92804.01912347642,
   'paris': 40908.82213277263,
   'perth': 65046.35819797423,
   'sydney': 43786.0579097594}
pop = {'france': 10000, 'china': 202434}

distance_limit = 10
selected_countries = [country for country, distance in distance_dict.items()
                      if distance > distance_limit]
selected_populations = [pop.get(country) for country in selected_countries 
                        if pop.get(country)]


>>>selected_populations
[202434]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Is it possible then from this to load the popdata for each item that appears in this list?

Comment: Where is your population data? I can only see the distances.

Comment: the population data is above the dic code in original question. See edit. Is it possible to load this population data if the station appears in the list you provided?

Comment: yes. But what i want to do is using your code that prints if a station is outside distance. Can i then only call the pop data for stations that appear in the greater than list?

Comment: Awesome thanks MIKE this does exactly what i want to do. Your help is very much appreciated.